# How to reconstruct a road network from gps coordinates

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to reconstruct a road network from a set of GPS coordinates.
I have done some research, but most existing algorithms seem to rely on having information about which coordinates are from the same car. I do not have any information on which points lie on a trace together. As a first step I am assuming that the coordinates are 100% accurate, to make it simpler. I realise that adding points at cross sections will be necessary to ensure there are no intersections. I also assume there are no roads going over or under each other.

So what I have: A set of points in a 2D plane.
What I need to compute: A fully connected network that connects all of these points. This should be the most likely road network.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to go about doing this?
I thought about starting off with a minimum spanning tree and going from there. But I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: First of all you should visualize all your points then you need to find out how they connect to each other e.g. via hidden markov model. But having the connection between the points would make this guessing much simpler I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have no information about the point. So dependent on your dataset, you could bruteforce it.

Start with a random point, find the closest point to this, connect these. Move to the new point, and find the closest point not connected to this. And then spread out from there.

You probably need to do some gymnastics to some cases, like endpoints, or when there are a long distance between two points that should be connected.

I'll try to give some examples when I get home later today, if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

> What I need to compute: A fully connected network that connects all of these points. This should be the most likely road network.
>
> Does anyone have any thoughts on how to go about doing this?

Not at all. It's impossible, unless you make *a lot* more statements about your individual positions.

> So what I have: A set of points in a 2D plane.

Look at it as a graph problem: You've got a bunch of nodes (your GPS coordinates) with no edges. So that's a graph, yes, but a totally disconnected one, hence:

> I thought about starting off with a minimum spanning tree and going from there.

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree):

> A minimum spanning tree is a spanning tree of a connected, undirected graph. It connects all the vertices together with the minimal total weighting for its edges.

That would require having a connected graph. You don't have one.

So how would you start connecting your points? You only have a set of points; a set as it isn't even ordered! Will you connect points to their nearest neighbor, ensuring some sort of restriction on the edges per node? Won't work in urban areas at all – there's main roads that are broader than the distance between back alleys, for example, under- and overpasses, a lot of streets that have lanes going in incompatible directions etc.